# how to use wsdl file and by using this service i need create Users in asp.net,c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice-client

I had .wsdl file, I added to my application. after that I added name space  also..

Now I need to create customers from my application using this WSDL file (Service)

How do I do this?

#### Update:

I got this .wsdl file from my client. they said this WSDL file have all services to access the there(client) Database and server.So from my application Using this wsdl file i need to insert new customer datails.  I added this this file to my application. now I need to some code  how use WSDL and using this how to insert the values.

```
<xs:complexType name="Customer">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Data required for the creation of a new customer record.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="PersonName" type="c:PersonName" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="EmailAddress" type="c:EmailAddress" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="Password" type="c:Password" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="Gender" type="c:Gender" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Address" type="c:Address" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PhoneAddress" type="c:Phone" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Does the service already create accounts, and you need to use it? Post the details of the wsdl here. Who provides the service? etc etc etc. The more infomration you give, the easier it is to help.

Answer (score 2):

- Add the service reference to your project (right click on your project and click Add Web Reference)
- Supply the address of your service
- You'll see that your service is included in the project under the Web References folder in Visual Studio.
- All you need to do is to create an instance of your service object and make service calls like:

If your reference name is x you should be able to:

```
x.ServiceClass myService = new x.ServiceClass();
myService.CreateUser(...);
```

replace ServiceClass with the right class name in your proxy (type x. and find your desired class which contains your method calls)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Service Reference (right-click on your project, Add Service Reference), which will generate proxy classes for you.

I'd suggest having a look at the WCF tutorials ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd728059 ) which show you both creating and consuming web services, here's a couple that cover building clients to services:

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Client/

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Configuring-WCF-Service-References/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from within Visual Studio, you need to use "SvcUtil.exe" to generate the client proxy classes in C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx

I suggest you do some general reading on WCF as well.